# Make different UICollectionViewCells conform to different layouts?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

**This is in regards to position not size.**

From what I've seen online, convention is usually to override the layout and implement your own custom properties using:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
```

and I have been able to set custom layout attributes. However, layoutAttributesForElement does the following according to the documentation:

Returns the layout attributes for all of the cells and views in the specified rectangle.

*"All of the cells"*

I want **two different cells** to conform to **two different sets of layout attributes** in the same view.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This method is called when you scroll for instance. It asks, from the rect I'm going to show to user, what are the cells and there frames to show. It doesn't take care of the type of cell, it's just asking for the frames to show if needed.

Comment: This method is the only method I've seen used when setting layout attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define different cell *prototypes*, not different layout attributes. Each one needs a unique identifier, and then in your collection data source's `collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)`, call the collection view's `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:)` with the identifier that you want for the given path.

Comment: When I register a second cell and call it conforms to the default layout attributes that I set.

Comment: Don't set layout attributes on the cell prototypes. Just use autolayout normally.

Comment: Auto layout on a UICollectionViewCell? I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Autolayout itself works just fine in collection view cells.